# Leg Press & Actual Lifted Weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, geometry

I was doing leg press at the gym today and was curious how much weight I actually lift when I do the exercise as compared to when I do a squat.

Suppose I load $w_L$ onto the machine, which has an angle of elevation $\theta$.  I know that the actual weight I lift vertically is $w_L \sin(\theta)$, but could someone give me an explanation why this is so?

My intuition is to appeal to simple trigonometry, which tells me the vertical side of the triangle is $w_L \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical component of moving weight at a 45 degree angle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17335/)

Comment: @Kyle, yes the linked question was sufficiently similar to mine.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compare the distance that your feet move to the distance that the weight moves. Then apply conservation of energy.